# jquery autocomplete is not working good with accentuation

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

i've some trouble with accentuation in autocomplete from jquery.
when i type a letter with accent i have the result like "M& Aacute;THEUS" instead "MÁTHEUS"
i tried to change utf8_encode to decode then i have "M?THEUS"

follow my code bellow

> retornar_cliente_processo.php

```
<?php require_once("conexao/conexao.php"); ?>
<?php
$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));//retrieve the search term that autocomplete sends

$qstring = "SELECT clienteNome as value,clienteId as id FROM cliente WHERE clienteNome LIKE '%".$term."%' LIMIT 10";

 $consulta_tr = mysqli_query($conecta, $qstring);
    if(!$consulta_tr) {
        die("erro no banco1");
    }

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_tr,MYSQL_ASSOC))//loop through the retrieved values
{
        $row['value']=htmlentities(stripslashes(utf8_encode($row['value'])));
        $row['id']=(int)$row['id'];
        $row_set[] = $row;//build an array
}
echo json_encode($row_set);//format the array into json data
?>
```

> js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#clientes').autocomplete({
    source: 'php/retornar_cliente_processo.php',
    minLength: 1,   

      select: function(event, ui) {

        $('#clienteId').val(ui.item.id);
        $('.form-control').removeAttr("disabled");  
        $('#clientes').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $('#alteraNome').removeAttr("disabled");        
             },
        }); }
```

> html

```
  <input type="hidden" name="clienteId" id="clienteId" placeholder="ID">   

      <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-md-12">
              <label for="clienteNome" class="control-label">Nome do cliente</label>

              <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="clienteNome" id="clientes"  class="form-control" placeholder="Nome do cliente" required>

              </div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Have you looked at / considered the accent folding described in this example? http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#folding  I think the end result is more desirable.  Otherwise, it would help to know where the encoding issue occurs.  Is it when posting back to the server or when querying the database?

Comment: `utf8_encode()`, ISO-8859-1/Latin-1 to UTF-8. Are you sure the encoding in Latin-1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, remove htmlentities(), that's why you get `M&Aacute;THEUS` instead of `MÁTHEUS`:

```
$row['value']=stripslashes(utf8_encode($row['value']));
```

Comment: wow ..Thanks a lot. after many attempts this solution solved perfectly

Comment: glad to help you! :)